# matplotlib scatter plot using relative coordinate?

Tags: matplotlib

I notice that there is an option of figure fraction etc for annotating text. Is there an option for scatter? I have data points generated by a program that are in figure fraction scale. They will be overplotted onto an image with sky coordinate. The transformation from pixel scale to sky coordinate will be a bit complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the transform [tutorial](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/transforms_tutotrial.html). You want to first transform from figure units to display units using `fig.transFigure`, then do the inverse transform to data units, using `ax.transData.inverted()`. You can make a single transform using transform pipeline:

```
FigToData = ax.transData.inverted() + fig.transFigure
```

This can then be used to get values in data units by implementing the `transform()` method:

```
xData, yData = FigToData.transform(.1, .1)
```

Read the tutorial for more detail.